# What does it mean to check for equality with self in python?

Tags: python

```
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self,key,val,left=None,right=None,
                                       parent=None):
        self.key = key
        self.payload = val
        self.leftChild = left
        self.rightChild = right
        self.parent = parent

    # Instance method
    def isLeftChild(self):
        return self.parent and self.parent.leftChild == self
```

What does the last line of this code snippet mean?

[Check this for complete code](https://runestone.academy/runestone/books/published/pythonds/Trees/SearchTreeImplementation.html)

Comment: just like any other equality check, except that `self` is the `TreeNode` object you are passing to the function...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
self.parent  # Make sure this is not a root node
and 
self.parent.leftChild == self  
# self = current node object, 
# check if current node's parent's leftChild attribute also 
# points to this current node object
```

Also, as [Dan D.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/388787/dan-d) mentions, you should use `is` instead of `==` since you want to compare whether the two nodes being compared point to the same object.

Answer (score 0):

When you call a method that you declared in a class, that means that you already made an instance from this class and you call a method from this instance.

This instance object will be passed to the method as the `self` argument

So making comparisons with `self` just means comparing with the object you call your method on.

In this specific case : `self.parent.leftChild == self` assumes that the `TreeNode` object you called `.isLeftChild()` on has an attribute `parent` which has an attribute `leftChild` which can itself be a `TreeNode` and it tests if it's the same `TreeNode` as himself.

Answer (score 0):

If we have parent, are we the left child of that parent?

The method should use `is` and not `==` as it is a test of identity and not of equality.